# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception (Linphone)

Tags: android, gradle, linphone

I am getting the following error while compiling linphone in Mac OS.

**Info:**
OS: Mac (Mojave)
Linphone: for Android
Android Studio: 3.1.2
Latest Android API: 28
NDK Version : 18.1.5063045

```
linphone-android root# make
./gradlew clean

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory().
> Could not create service of type PluginResolutionStrategyInternal using BuildScopeServices.createPluginResolutionStrategy().

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong...

Comment: Any Luck so far ?? Also looking to resolve same issue.